# New user is part of a group it was never added to

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, android-adapter

I'm currently working on an app in which users can create groups and add members to groups. Today I created a new user to test the app. When I logged in this new user I checked to see if it was a part of any groups, which I didn't expect it to be seeing as it was new. And it wasn't. But then when I logged in my usual user and clicked groups I saw the name of the test user. Why does it appear that this user is a part of a group it was never added to?

It should be noted that when looking through my firebase this test user doesn't appear to have been invited either. I'm using firestore recycler adapter to fetch data in a recyclerView.

Below is the code for my adapter responsible for adding members to a specific group.

FirestoreMemberAdapter.java:

```
public class FirestoreMemberAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<MemberModel, FirestoreMemberAdapter.MemberViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = FirestoreMemberAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private Context context;
private String projectId;
private String projectName;

public FirestoreMemberAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MemberModel> options, Context context, String projectId, String projectName) {
    super(options);
    this.context = context;
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.projectId = projectId;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MemberViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final MemberModel model) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(model.getName());
    if (model.getProfile_image() == null) {
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.mImageview);
    } else {
        Picasso.get().load(model.getProfile_image()).into(holder.mImageview);
    }
    holder.mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Clicked on FirestoreMemberAdapter ");
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileMemberPage.class);
            intent.putExtra(StringCreator.PROJECT_TITLE, projectName);
            intent.putExtra(StringCreator.PROJECT_ID, projectId);
            intent.putExtra(StringCreator.NAME, model.getName());
            intent.putExtra(StringCreator.EMAIL, model.getEmail());
            intent.putExtra(StringCreator.USER_ID, model.getUser_id());
            intent.putExtra(StringCreator.USER_INFORMATION, model.getUser_information());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MemberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_projectmembers, parent, false);
    return new MemberViewHolder(view);
}

public class MemberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private ImageView mImageview;

    public MemberViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memberTitle);
        mLinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_members);
        mImageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memberImage);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the activity in wihch the adapter is used.

projectClicked.java:

```
 //widgets
private RecyclerView recyclerViewMembers;
private TextView projectName;
private Button cameraBtn;
private FloatingActionButton addUserBtn;
//Firebase
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private Query query;
private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MemberModel> options;
private FirestoreMemberAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_clicked);

    projectName = findViewById(R.id.projectName);
    addUserBtn = findViewById(R.id.addUserBtn);
    cameraBtn = findViewById(R.id.cameraBtn);

    initRecyclerView();

    addUserBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(projectClicked.this, UserToProject.class);
            Bundle projectBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (projectBundle != null) {
                newIntent.putExtras(projectBundle);
            }
            startActivity(newIntent);
        }
    });
}

private void initRecyclerView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "InitRecyclerView: init recyclerview");
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(StringCreator.PROJECT_TITLE) && getIntent().hasExtra(StringCreator.PROJECT_ID)) {
        final String pName = getIntent().getStringExtra(StringCreator.PROJECT_TITLE);
        final String pID = getIntent().getStringExtra(StringCreator.PROJECT_ID);
        projectName.setText(pName);

        recyclerViewMembers = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_members);
        query = firebaseFirestore.collection("users");
        options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<MemberModel>().setQuery(query, MemberModel.class).build();
        adapter = new FirestoreMemberAdapter(options, projectClicked.this, pID, pName);

        recyclerViewMembers.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewMembers.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerViewMembers.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(projectClicked.this));
    }
}

 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Hope this makes sense, please reach out if it doesn't. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not know firestore well, but it seems like you just get all users and do not filter them by groups.

Comment: You were right.. i changed my query to this `query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Groups").document(pID).collection(pName);` in **projectClicked.java** and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @McSlinPlay mentioned, the reason could be pointed out to your code in **projectClicked.java** where you created your query and all the users (including the test user) are part of this collection:

```
query = firebaseFirestore.collection("users");
```